# Google MDL: drawer icon not centered

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I'm trying the [fixed tab example](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout) from the Google MDL documentation. Here is my code:

**CODE**

```
<!-- Simple header with fixed tabs. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-tabs">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a href="#fixed-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
          <a href="#fixed-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout__title">Title</span>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="fixed-tab-1">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-2">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="fixed-tab-3">
          <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Fixed Tabs]

The problem is my drawer icon position is wrong!  It is aligned to the top instead of center. What is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material Design Lite hamburger menu not centered in header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793815/material-design-lite-hamburger-menu-not-centered-in-header)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879018/2684718) and it solved the problem! You need to add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the source and everything will work properly.